# How can I make Illustrator reopen the files I was previously working on?

Tags: adobe-illustrator

I can't for the life of me find a way to tell Illustrator to save the files that I have currently open and reopen them after I restart. Am I missing an obvious setting?

Comment: You mean besides `File -> Open Recent Files...`?

Comment: Yeah, I don't want to open each recent file individually. Also, the tabs should be in the right order

Comment: Can you do that in any Adobe programs?

Comment: Adobe Indesign can save previously opened files, and I'm pretty sure my old illustrator CS5 did it, but I can't seem to find it anywhere too?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That can't be done.

You can use Bridge to open several files at once (or just select them all in the Finder/Explorer).

But there's no way to specifically control how tabs are ordered.

Nice idea. Just not possible as far as I know. No Adobe app retains "sessions" like you describe.